# Convergence radius of the Operator Product Expansion in non-conformal QFTs

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory

As by the Wikipedia definition, an OPE in QFT is a convergent expansion of the product of two operators at different spacetime points in terms of a sum of (possibly infinitely many) local operators.
In Conformal Field Theories it can be proven that the radius of convergence of this series must be at least as big as that of the biggest circle centered around one of the operators which does not contain any other operator insertions.

My questions are:

1) What can be said about the radius of convergence of the OPE of two operators in the non-conformal case?

2) If we cannot guarantee a non-zero radius for the general case in a general QFT, is there usually some meaningful subgroup of operators for which the OPE has better properties? Maybe considering only operators with the same scaling dimension? (even if scale invariance is not present in the theory)

Comment: In perturbative QFTs, there is a some work by Hollands et al. on the convergence of OPE expansion at arbitrary finite loop order. See  https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3375 for the case of massive Euclidean phi^4 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1785 for the massless analogue. Whether or not these OPE coefficients make sense nonperturbatively I have no idea (it seems difficult with current QFT technology).